# GPUs not being used while running Keras code

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, nvidia, python-3.7

I need to know how to run the keras code on GPUs. This is for a Ubuntu server. P.S. I am just starting to figure out stuff in Deep Learning and running on GPU.

I've seen some code to execute in python3 to display the cpu and gpus that you can use. This is what it shows

[image: SNAP 01]

This is the output after nvidia-smi(It's a college server xD)

[image: SNAP 2]

In my python code, I have included this to run on GPU

[image: SNAP 3]

Output

[image: SNAP 4]

Comment: Did you install tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: Yepp I did. But both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu are installed.

Comment: You cannot have both installed at the same time, so there are many details that you are not mentioning.